# C++ error when defining array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im trying to declare an array in C++ but i keep getting this error.

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int []'

for this line

```
int b[] = new int[elements];
```

***Full Code***

```
int* reverseArray (int a[] ,int elements)
{
    int *pointer;
    int x= elements-1;
    int b[] = new int[elements];
    pointer=b[];
    for (int i= 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[x--];
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

Comment: You are asking for a memory leak even if you fix the allocation and swapping of values. Instead consider using `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`new` returns a pointer, so you should change

```
int b[] = new int[elements];
```

to

```
int* b = new int[elements];
```

and you should just remove `pointer` and simply return `b`, so

```
int* reverseArray (int a[] ,int elements)
{
  int x = elements-1;
  int* b = new int[elements];
  for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i)
    b[i] = a[x--];
  return b;
}
```

But you should really consider using `std::vector`. If you use a `std::vector`, to reverse the array, you can simply use `std::reverse` from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: for pointer = b it throws  cannot convert from 'int *[]' to 'int *'

Comment: i'm not allowed to use vectors...class assignment

Comment: @atbyrd In that case, keep them in mind for the future. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: @atbyrd: You didn't read carefully. You wrote `int *b[]`, which is an array of pointers to int.  `new` returns a pointer!  You need to declare `b` as `int *b`;

Answer (score 0):

Use [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) - lot easier to use

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't help a beginner understand anything, so -1.  Understanding concepts is far more useful than being told to use a library (of course, he should use a vector, but that is tangential to the problem at hand).

Comment: I cannot put verbatim into the library. Just would not like to put that person that that person can achieve a lot more by using a library. I would have not quarrel or contempt if they want to ask any question.

Comment: Ok, I just don't think this is a useful answer for a beginner.

Comment: @EdS. - I did give a link to the appropriate web site so that person can learn STL.

Comment: Very true, but this should be a comment (which someone else already posted), not an answer.

Comment: @Eds = that was my answer. I like to teach people by example.

Comment: Not really teaching though.  Op says "I don't understand basic types or how to allocate memory dynamically", you say - "use a vector".